# Custom error handler is returning a lot of debug messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to create custom exception handler which returns a structured JSON response with data. I tried this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(BaseException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> handleException(BaseException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
        ErrorResponse errorEntry = new ErrorResponse();
        errorEntry.setTitle(ex.getTitle());
        errorEntry.setCode(ex.getErrorCode());
        HttpStatus httpStatus = ErrorDetail.getHttpStatusBasedOnErrorCode(ex.getErrorCode());
        errorEntry.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
        errorEntry.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
        errorEntry.setExtra(ex.getExtra());

        ErrorResponseDTO errorResponse = new ErrorResponseDTO();
        errorResponse.setErrors(Arrays.asList(errorEntry));

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO>(errorResponse, httpStatus);
    }
```

Full code: [Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/pull/14/files#diff-cfeebc36d9480137805f87534232c6fb)

But I get this huge result:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "stackTrace": [
                {
                    "methodName": "handleException",
                    "fileName": "EngineExceptionHandler.java",
                    "lineNumber": 66,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.engine.exception.EngineExceptionHandler"
                },
                {
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "14",
                    "methodName": "invoke0",
                    "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
                    "lineNumber": -2,
                    "nativeMethod": true,
                    "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl"
                },
                {
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "14",
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
                    "lineNumber": 62,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl"
                },
                {
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "14",
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
                    "lineNumber": 43,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl"
                },
                {
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "14",
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "Method.java",
                    "lineNumber": 564,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doInvoke",
                    "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
                    "lineNumber": 190,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invokeForRequest",
                    "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
                    "lineNumber": 138,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invokeAndHandle",
                    "fileName": "ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java",
                    "lineNumber": 105,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doResolveHandlerMethodException",
                    "fileName": "ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java",
                    "lineNumber": 407,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doResolveException",
                    "fileName": "AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java",
                    "lineNumber": 61,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "resolveException",
                    "fileName": "AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java",
                    "lineNumber": 141,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "resolveException",
                    "fileName": "HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java",
                    "lineNumber": 80,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "processHandlerException",
                    "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 1300,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "processDispatchResult",
                    "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 1111,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doDispatch",
                    "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 1057,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doService",
                    "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 943,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "processRequest",
                    "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 1006,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doPost",
                    "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 909,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "service",
                    "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 660,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "service",
                    "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 883,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "service",
                    "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
                    "lineNumber": 741,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 231,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 166,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "WsFilter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 53,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 193,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 166,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
                    "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
                    "lineNumber": 209,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "FilterChainProxy.java",
                    "lineNumber": 178,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invokeDelegate",
                    "fileName": "DelegatingFilterProxy.java",
                    "lineNumber": 358,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "DelegatingFilterProxy.java",
                    "lineNumber": 271,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 193,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 166,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
                    "fileName": "RequestContextFilter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 100,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 119,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 193,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 166,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
                    "fileName": "FormContentFilter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 93,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 119,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 193,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 166,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
                    "fileName": "CharacterEncodingFilter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 201,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 119,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 193,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doFilter",
                    "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
                    "lineNumber": 166,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "StandardWrapperValve.java",
                    "lineNumber": 202,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "StandardContextValve.java",
                    "lineNumber": 96,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "AuthenticatorBase.java",
                    "lineNumber": 541,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "StandardHostValve.java",
                    "lineNumber": 139,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "ErrorReportValve.java",
                    "lineNumber": 92,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "invoke",
                    "fileName": "StandardEngineValve.java",
                    "lineNumber": 74,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "service",
                    "fileName": "CoyoteAdapter.java",
                    "lineNumber": 343,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "service",
                    "fileName": "Http11Processor.java",
                    "lineNumber": 373,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "process",
                    "fileName": "AbstractProcessorLight.java",
                    "lineNumber": 65,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "process",
                    "fileName": "AbstractProtocol.java",
                    "lineNumber": 868,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "doRun",
                    "fileName": "NioEndpoint.java",
                    "lineNumber": 1590,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "run",
                    "fileName": "SocketProcessorBase.java",
                    "lineNumber": 49,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase"
                },
                {
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "14",
                    "methodName": "runWorker",
                    "fileName": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
                    "lineNumber": 1130,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor"
                },
                {
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "14",
                    "methodName": "run",
                    "fileName": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
                    "lineNumber": 630,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker"
                },
                {
                    "methodName": "run",
                    "fileName": "TaskThread.java",
                    "lineNumber": 61,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable"
                },
                {
                    "moduleName": "java.base",
                    "moduleVersion": "14",
                    "methodName": "run",
                    "fileName": "Thread.java",
                    "lineNumber": 832,
                    "nativeMethod": false,
                    "className": "java.lang.Thread"
                }
            ],
            "status": 404,
            "code": "1000",
            "title": "Title not found",
            "detail": "Message not found",
            "extra": {
                "detail": "Detail not found",
                "message": "Message not found",
                "httpStatusCode": "404"
            },
            "suppressed": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get only this result:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {          
            "status": 404,
            "code": "1000",
            "title": "Not found",
            "detail": "item Not found",
            "extra": {
                "detail": "values are not found"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you know why I get all this error data and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please remove "extends Throwable" from your ErrorResponse.java class and have a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the [github link](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/pull/14/files#diff-cfeebc36d9480137805f87534232c6fb) it seems that [`ErrorResponse extends Throwable`](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/pull/14/files#diff-7423f681f185fa0b2a0b949aaf99c27bR10).

relevant code for future reference:

```
...
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
...

@Setter
@Getter
public class ErrorResponse extends Throwable {

    private int status;

    private String code;
...
```

this explain why you get a [`stackTrace` array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace--) in the json response.

when you create a new `ErrorResponse` object:

```
ErrorResponse errorEntry = new ErrorResponse();
```

the no-args costructuor of `Throwable` (super class of `ErrorResponse`) gets also called and it fills the `stackTrace` array with the current state of the stack:

> [**public Throwable()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#Throwable--)
>
> Constructs a new throwable with null as its detail message.
>
> ...
>
> The fillInStackTrace() method is called to initialize the stack trace
>   data in the newly created throwable.

to obtain your desired result, `ErrorResponse` should not extend `Throwable`:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class ErrorResponse {

    private int status;

    private String code;
...
```